# Can't test OPTIONS method using mocha and supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, supertest

The related question [Cant test DELETE method using mocha and supertest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20316373/881286) and its current two answers didn't solved my issue :(

The following is the test definition:

```
api = supertest(url);

describe('when OPTIONS', function () {
    it('should return only method GET', function (done) {
      api
        .options('/')
        .expect('Allow', 'GET')
        .expect(200, done);
    });
  });
```

Its keeping triggering the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of undefined
      at _stream_readable.js:944:16
```

and when:

```
 api
        .options('/')
        .end(function(error,res){
          if (error) return done(error);
          done()
        });
```

It says:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token G
      at Object.parse (native)
      at _stream_readable.js:944:16
```

I already tried a lot of things without being able to make this work.

I 'm using supertest `^1.0.1` and it worked fine with version `~0.13.0`.

Related issue at https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/272

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce. Are you sure the responses from your API are valid?

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for your comment, it was very useful for detect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I already detected the issue, it was that in the API I was returning an OPTIONS response with `Content-Type: application/json` but the body was an invalid JSON (it was GET,HEAD).